# Serve webpages with PHP, WordPress style

Tags: php, dynamic

For a "classic" website, one would create a `/foldername/index.php` for every web page. With WordPress, however, this is not the case. For example, if a page was created with WordPress whose URI was `http://myblog.org/some_page`, you would not find the folder `www/myblog.org/some_page` in your web host's FTP.

My question then, is, How can I serve up pages located at `http://[MY_WEBSITE].com/[page_name]` for any arbitrary `page_name`, without creating a new folder for every `page_name`?

Comment: Look into [htaccess' mod_rewrite](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is handled (in an Apache server) by a `.htaccess` file, wherein [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are defined. Rewrite rules basically capture incoming traffic and directs those requests to a file on the server (typically a single page which will act as a `router`).

The router is then responsible for taking the input URI (usually via [`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in PHP) and working out what to do with it, and ultimately what the output will be for that request.

As for a decent router, you could look at [`klein.php`](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php). Also, a brief example:

```
# htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+$ index.php
```

And the `index.php`:

```
$route = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if($route === '/home')
{
    echo 'This is the homepage';
}
```

Comment: This is old, but I changed the second rule to `RewriteRule . index.php [L] 
` and it works beautifully

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use the page_name as parameter to a common file and use that to serve the contents of the required page.

Comment: Would this involve changing the URL to something like `my-website.com/index.php?page=somepage` ? Otherwise how would you do it?

Comment: I do know about that feature, but that's not exactly what I want. I would still like to keep the `my-site.com/my-page/my-subpage/ ...` URL style, and not have to create a separate `index.php` page for every page.

Comment: then Marty Wallace's answer is better suited

Answer (score 0):

You tell your server to [*rewrite the URL*](http://google.com/search?q=server+url+rewriting). Most servers do it in their own way, so to find out how to do it look at your server's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses templates that make use of the `require()` function and a foreach loop commonly called "The Loop" to retreive content.

Different pages are called using different templates. If you want to know exactly how this logic is calculated, look into [this.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)